# Is there another way to look at an "AND" type of questions like this?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**I have the following question:**

List all customer and product information for all products sold in January 2016 to customers whose last name starts with the letter 'O'.

**From which I wrote the following:**

```
SELECT  CUS_LNAME,
customer.CUS_CODE,
CUS_FNAME, 
CUS_INITIAL, 
CUS_AREACODE, 
CUS_PHONE, 
CUS_BALANCE,
CUS_PPBAL,
P_DESCRIPT, P_CODE, vendor.V_CODE, P_QOH, P_REORDER, 
P_INDATE, P_DISCOUNT, P_PRICE, P_MIN

FROM customer
JOIN product
JOIN vendor
JOIN invoice ON invoice.CUS_CODE=customer.CUS_CODE
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2016-01-01')
GROUP BY product.P_CODE
HAVING CUS_LNAME LIKE 'O%';
```

Yields the following error:

```
ERROR 1055 (42000) at line 1: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mimir.customer.CUS_LNAME' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
query returned no results!
```

After reading the question multiple times I came with the idea of just printing the the name of every customer that bought something on this date  with the last name starting with O:

```
SELECT  CUS_LNAME,
    customer.CUS_CODE,
    CUS_FNAME, 
    CUS_INITIAL, 
    CUS_AREACODE, 
    CUS_PHONE, 
    CUS_BALANCE,
    CUS_PPBAL,
    P_DESCRIPT, P_CODE, vendor.V_CODE, P_QOH, P_REORDER, 
    P_INDATE, P_DISCOUNT, P_PRICE, P_MIN

    FROM customer
    JOIN product
    JOIN vendor
    JOIN invoice ON invoice.CUS_CODE=customer.CUS_CODE
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2016-01-01') AND CUS_LNAME LIKE 'O%';
```

The Query does work on MySQL Workbench but curiously does not work on the online tool(Mimir) I use to submit my answer. Furthermore, with no feedbacks given, I left with contemplating the essence of the question. It does not give any feedback but just a mere: `rows incorrect!`

I do not believe changing the order of  my `JOIN` or the table on which I use the `FROM` will change anything.

Any feedback or tip will be more than appreciated. Here's an ERD for the aforementioned question.

[image]

Comment: If you `group by product.P_CODE` the output will contain a unique P_CODE, but there could be multiple customers for that P_CODE. Which customer do you display per P_CODE?

Comment: Exactly! This is why I think that I may be missing  something from the question

Comment: Try your second query with JOIN `ON` criteria between invoice and line, and line an product, and product and vendor. `EXTRACT` is incorrect. Its a constant expression. `YEAR(INV_DATE)=2016 AND MONTH(INV_DATE)=1`

Comment: By incorrect you meant extract does not belong here? If so, the question also asks to use the EXRACT datetime function. That is why I wrote it. I'll try what you mentioned !

Comment: Tried, but get nothing. Here's the db sourcecode https://pastebin.com/HuCyt0Gr

Comment: [EXTRACT fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d5a424c86fb0b93b597c8d587c7f40a) shows the expression has a fixed value '201601' and isn't dependent only any data. Being >0 its always true. You perhaps want `WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM INV_DATE)=201601 ...` as an alternative to `YEAR`/`MONTH` functions.